# How to upload and retrieve image using sqlite databse

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

My question is in Xamarin.Forms using the SQLite database can upload an image and retrieve it to the same place(like a profile picture).

I look through google but I couldn't find anything like this is this possible to do in xamarin.Forms using SQLite local database

Comment: Yes it is possible using SQLite database!

Comment: any document to read I am using SQLite in xamarin forms are xamarin form will support it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Watch this little example:

Just convert your image to a byte array, you can use:

`byte[] myimage = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("pathtoimage")`

insert the image into your sql lite db:

```
public bool InsertMessage()
{

    SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand(con);

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Images(Data) VALUES (@img)";
        cmd.Prepare();

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", DbType.Binary, myimage.Length);
        cmd.Parameters["@img"].Value = myimage;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
}
```

to retrive the image and store it to a file:

```
 using(SqliteConnection con = new SqliteConnection(cs))
        {            
            con.Open();

            SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand(con);   
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Data FROM Images WHERE Id=1";
            byte[] data = (byte[]) cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            try
            {               
                if (data != null)
                { 
                    File.WriteAllBytes("woman2.jpg", data);
                    myimage = data
                } else 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Binary data not read");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }            

            con.Close();
        }
```

if you want save the image into a bitmap var:

```
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(myimage);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

Comment: this is how to insert the image how I retrieve it.

Comment: i've added the retrive method

Comment: MyImageLogo = MyByteArray variable  whats this variable and is MyByteArray is a data type  it does not support xamarin

Comment: Gianmarco Varriale  can you suggest anything.how to fix this

Comment: private void uploadimage()
        {
            database = new Database();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(database.Conn);

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Images(Data) VALUES (@img)";
            cmd.Prepare();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", DbType.Binary, myimage.Length);
            cmd.Parameters["@img"].Value = myimage;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            database.Conn.Close();
        }

Comment: you miss  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: 'SQLiteCommand' does not contain a definition for 'Prepare' and no accessible extension method 'Prepare' accepting a first argument of type 'SQLiteCommand' could be found

Comment: try to remove the cmd.prepare() and add the  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189178/discussion-between-ish1104-and-gianmarco-varriale).